# comparing float/double values using == operator

Tags: java, floating-point

The code review tool I use complains with the below when I start comparing two float values using equality operator. What is the correct way and how to do it? Is there a helper function (commons-*) out there which I can reuse?

**Description**

Cannot compare floating-point values using the equals (==) operator

**Explanation**

Comparing floating-point values by using either the equality (==) or inequality (!=) operators is not always accurate because of rounding errors.

**Recommendation**

Compare the two float values to see if they are close in value.

```
float a;
float b;

if(a==b)
{
..
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, if you are using `float` and it involves money (or really any number usually represented as decimals) you should consider `BigDecimal`.

Comment: good comment. I am aware of this and I use BigDecimal for all monetary stuff. But this is for everything else.

Comment: The use of java.lang.Float.compare(float1, float2); //returns integer value but it cannot be used instead of float1 == float2 in the if condition

Comment: Uhhh, what's wrong with 'if ( java.lang.Float.compare(float1, float2) == 0) { ... }'? That looks like a valid if condition to me!

Comment: @ingyhere. Float.compare(f1, f2) is actually using `compareTo` to do the comparison and in its [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo(java.lang.Float)), where it's clearly pointed out there are two exceptions compared to numerical comparisons. 1. Float.NaN is considered by this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other float values (including Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY).
2. 0.0f is considered by this method to be greater than -0.0f. So to sum up, it's not stable method to compare two floats using this method especially in critical scenarios.

Comment: @Hearen You actually have that backwards. Float1.compareTo (Float2) is using Float.compare(f1.f2). Irrespective, the return values are awkward. I guess it's up to the developer to decide if they need to sanitize inputs for their particular use case. I don't disagree with you.

Comment: @ingyhere You're right, I just checked the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.compare%28float%2Cfloat%29). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[IBM has a recommendation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/#N10255) for comparing two floats, using division rather than subtraction - this makes it easier to select an epsilon that works for all ranges of input.

```
if (abs(a/b - 1) < epsilon)
```

As for the value of epsilon, I would use `5.96e-08` as given in [this Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Values_for_standard_hardware_floating_point_arithmetics), or perhaps 2x that value.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, good question. You can check that condition with `if (abs(b) <= 1.18e−38)` and if it's true, then check `a` for the same condition to see if it's equal.

Comment: Ick.  Not only is that code horribly slow, it's also apt to be just plain wrong in a lot of cases.  If one is comparing e.g. x to (y-z), the tolerance needs to be based upon the size of y and z, not the size of the difference, and there's no way for code like the above to take that into consideration.  Exact equality testing between x and y is often appropriate if e.g. one has computed f(x) and wants to know if one should bother computing f(y) [or simply use the value of f(x)].  Unfortunately, exact equality testing is often difficult, though the `==` operator is good enough in most cases.

Comment: Not sure exactly how Java's Math.abs() method does it, but absolute values can be calculated very fast with bit shifting ops: http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=132 . ...

Comment: The suggested epsilon of `5.96e-08` is too small to be of practical value: there are *no* pairs `a` and `b` of distinct single-precision IEEE 754 floats such that `abs(a / b - 1) < 5.96e-08`, so with this epsilon this test just amounts to a slow way to test equality.

Answer (score 10):

It wants you to compare them to within the amount of accuracy you need. For example if you require that the first 4 decimal digits of your floats are equal, then you would use:

```
if(-0.00001 <= a-b && a-b <= 0.00001)
{
..
}
```

Or:

```
if(Math.abs(a-b) < 0.00001){ ... }
```

Where you add the desired precision to the difference of the two numbers and compare it to twice the desired precision.

Whatever you think is more readable. I prefer the first one myself as it clearly shows the precision you are allowing on both sides.

`a = 5.43421` and `b = 5.434205` will pass the comparison

Comment: if `a` is 2 and `b` is 3, the first comparison will fail (correctly), but the second will pass (incorrectly).

Answer (score 6):

```
private static final float EPSILON = <very small positive number>;

if (Math.abs(a-b) < EPSILON)
   ...
```

As floating point offers you variable but uncontrollable precision (that is, you can't set the precision other than when you choose between using `double` and `float`), you have to pick your own fixed precision for comparisons.

Note that this isn't a true equivalence operator any more, as it isn't transitive. You can easily get `a` equals `b` and `b` equals `c` but `a` not equals `c`.

*Edit: also note that if `a` is negative and `b` is a very large positive number, the subtraction can overflow and the result will be negative infinity, but the test will still work, as the absolute value of negative infinity is positive infinity, which will be bigger than `EPSILON`.*

Comment: can you please explain what should be the actual value for EPSILON?

Comment: Would define EPSILON as application-domain specific maximum tolerance, personally.  It could actually be a fairly large number if the numbers being compared are very large! :)

Comment: @Affe Exactly. It will depend on the application itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use commons-lang

```
org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils#compare
```

Also commons-math (in your situation more appropriate solution):

```
http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html#equals(double, double)
```

Comment: That function does nothing to mitigate the concern his tool is raising.

Comment: @Affe Which one? compare - agree; equals in commons-math does pretty the same as other answers state, also cool overloaded versions are presented in the MathUtils.

Comment: Yes, the approach used in MathUtils#equals is normally the best solution unless the application domain defines something more coarse.  First comment was on your pre-edit answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The `float` type is an *approximate* value - there's an exponent portion and a value portion with finite accuracy.
For example:

```
System.out.println((0.6 / 0.2) == 3);  // false
```

The risk is that a tiny rounding error can make a comparison `false`, when *mathematically* it should be `true`.

The workaround is to compare floats allowing a minor difference to still be "equal":

```
static float e = 0.00000000000001f;
if (Math.abs(a - b) < e)
```

Apache [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) to the rescue: [MathUtils.(double x, double y, int maxUlps)](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html#equals%28double,%20double,%20int%29)

> Returns true if both arguments are equal or within the range of allowed error (inclusive). Two float numbers are considered equal if there are (maxUlps - 1) (or fewer) floating point numbers between them, i.e. two adjacent floating point numbers are considered equal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual code form the Commons Math implementation:

```
private static final int SGN_MASK_FLOAT = 0x80000000;

public static boolean equals(float x, float y, int maxUlps) {
    int xInt = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    int yInt = Float.floatToIntBits(y);

    if (xInt < 0)
        xInt = SGN_MASK_FLOAT - xInt;

    if (yInt < 0)
        yInt = SGN_MASK_FLOAT - yInt;

    final boolean isEqual = Math.abs(xInt - yInt) <= maxUlps;

    return isEqual && !Float.isNaN(x) && !Float.isNaN(y);
}
```

This gives you the number of floats that can be represented between your two values at the current scale, which should work better than an absolute epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at this based on the way java implements == for doubles. It converts to the IEEE 754 long integer form first and then does a bitwise compare. Double also provides the static doubleToLongBits() to get the integer form. Using bit fiddling you can 'round' the mantissa of the double by adding 1/2 (one bit) and truncating.

In keeping with supercat's observation, the function first tries a simple == comparison and only rounds if that fails. Here is what I came up with some (hopefully) helpful comments.

I did some limited testing, but can't say I've tried all edge cases. Also, I did not test performance. It shouldn't be too bad.

I just realized that this is essentially the same solution as the one offered by Dmitri. Perhaps a bit more concise.

```
static public boolean nearlyEqual(double lhs, double rhs){
    // This rounds to the 6th mantissa bit from the end. So the numbers must have the same sign and exponent and the mantissas (as integers)
    // need to be within 32 of each other (bottom 5 bits of 52 bits can be different). 
    // To allow 'n' bits of difference create an additive value of 1<<(n-1) and a mask of 0xffffffffffffffffL<<n
    // e.g. 4 bits are: additive: 0x10L = 0x1L << 4 and mask: 0xffffffffffffffe0L = 0xffffffffffffffffL << 5
    //int bitsToIgnore = 5;
    //long additive = 1L << (bitsToIgnore - 1);
    //long mask = ~0x0L << bitsToIgnore; 
    //return ((Double.doubleToLongBits(lhs)+additive) & mask) == ((Double.doubleToLongBits(rhs)+additive) & mask);
    return lhs==rhs?true:((Double.doubleToLongBits(lhs)+0x10L) & 0xffffffffffffffe0L) == ((Double.doubleToLongBits(rhs)+0x10L) & 0xffffffffffffffe0L);
}
```

The following modification handles the change in sign case where the value is on either side of 0.

```
return lhs==rhs?true:((Double.doubleToLongBits(lhs)+0x10L) & 0x7fffffffffffffe0L) == ((Double.doubleToLongBits(rhs)+0x10L) & 0x7fffffffffffffe0L);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases where one wants to regard two floating-point numbers as equal only if they are absolutely equivalent, and a "delta" comparison would be wrong.  For example, if f is a pure function), and one knows that q=f(x) and y===x, then one should know that q=f(y) without having to compute it.  Unfortunately the == has two defects in this regard.

- If one value is positive zero and the other is negative zero, they will compare as equal even though they are not necessarily equivalent.  For example if f(d)=1/d, a=0 and b=-1*a, then a==b but f(a)!=f(b).
- If either value is a NaN, the comparison will always yield false even if one value was assigned directly from the other.

Although there are many cases where checking floating-point numbers for exact equivalence is right and proper, I'm not sure about any cases where the actual behavior of `==` should be considered preferable.  Arguably, all tests for equivalence should be done via a function that actually tests equivalence (e.g. by comparing bitwise forms).

Answer (score 0):

First, a few things to note:

- The "Standard" way to do this is to choose an constant epsilon, but constant epsilons do not work correctly for all number ranges.
- If you want to use a constant epsilon `sqrt(EPSILON)` the square root of the epsilon from `float.h` is a generally considered a good value. (this comes from an infamous "orange book" who's name escapes me at the moment).
- Floating point division is going to be slow, so you probably want to avoid it for comparisons even if it behaves like picking an epsilon that is custom made for the numbers' magnitudes.

What do you really want to do? something like this:
**Compare how many representable floating point numbers the values differ by.**

This code comes from [this](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) really great article by Bruce Dawson. The article has been since updated [here](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). The main difference is the old article breaks the strict-aliasing rule. (casting floating pointers to int pointer, dereferencing, writing, casting back). While the C/C++ purist will quickly point out the flaw, in practice this works, and I consider the code more readable. However, the new article uses unions and C/C++ gets to keep its dignity. For brevity I give the code that breaks strict aliasing below.

```
// Usable AlmostEqual function
bool AlmostEqual2sComplement(float A, float B, int maxUlps)
{
    // Make sure maxUlps is non-negative and small enough that the
    // default NAN won't compare as equal to anything.
    assert(maxUlps > 0 && maxUlps < 4 * 1024 * 1024);
    int aInt = *(int*)&A;
    // Make aInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    if (aInt < 0)
        aInt = 0x80000000 - aInt;
    // Make bInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    int bInt = *(int*)&B;
    if (bInt < 0)
        bInt = 0x80000000 - bInt;
    int intDiff = abs(aInt - bInt);
    if (intDiff <= maxUlps)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The basic idea in the code above is to first notice that given the IEEE 754 floating point format, `{sign-bit, biased-exponent, mantissa}`, that the numbers are lexicographically ordered if interpreted as signed magnitude ints. That is the sign bit becomes the sign bit, the and the exponent always completely outranks the mantissa in defining magnitude of the float and because it comes first in determining the magnitude of the number interpreted as an int.

So, we interpret the bit representation of the floating point number as a signed-magnitude int. We then convert the signed-magnitude ints to a two's complement ints by subtracting them from 0x80000000 if the number is negative. Then we just compare the two values as we would any signed two's complement ints, and seeing how many values they differ by. If this amount is less than the threshold you choose for how many representable floats the values may differ by and still be considered equal, then you say that they are "equal." Note that this method correctly lets "equal" numbers differ by larger values for larger magnitude floats, and by smaller values for smaller magnitude floats.