# How to use if/else condition in Hadoop mapreduce programming?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and writing mapreduce code and in mapper class i am using one if condition in following way:-

```
public class FilmDataMapperClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException
            {
                String line = values.toString();
                String [] data = line.split(",");
                word.set(data[3]);
                float rating = Float.valueOf(data[3]);
                if(rating > 3.0)
                {
                    output.collect(word, new IntWritable(1));
                }
            }
}
```

When i am using above code without any if condition then i am getting output but with if condition i am not getting any output.

Please tell me how to implement above to get desired output.

Comment: Floating point values using direct conditional operators may not be accurate. Check [this similar] question.

Comment: you can use `Float.compare(f1,f2);` for comparing two float values. It will returns the value 0 if f1 is numerically equal to f2; a value less than 0 if f1 is numerically less than f2; and a value greater than 0 if f1 is numerically greater than f2.

Comment: please share the link of similar question @learningloop

Comment: @ChandanMishra Sorry, My bad. Following is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837007/comparing-float-double-values-using-operator)

Comment: `Float.compare(f1, f2)` is also not working @Rockstar

Comment: i also tried to use compare() function but this also did not work - @learningloop

Comment: So what value are you getting at `float rating = Float.valueOf(data[3]);` try to log and check.

Comment: i am getting float value. And when i am putting `system.out.println(rating)` inside if condition then i am getting proper output but i am not getting anything in `output.collect(word, new IntWritable(1))` @Rockstar
@learningloop