# How to test for equality of float/double in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

The `assertEquals(double,double)` method is justifiably deprecated.  Is there an alternate and/or different approach baked into junit - or do I roll my own tiny extension

```
  static boolean assertEquals(double d1, double d2) {
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2) < 1e-8;
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use `assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)` instead.

Comment: Thanks that's the answer i needed.

Comment: Personally, I tend to think `Assert.assertThat( actual, CoreMatchers.closeTo( expected, delta ) )` is a little bit nicer to read, especially with static imports ( `assertThat( actual, closeTo( expected, delta ) )` ) - but ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of JUnit, there is already made functions.

But in other type of Java code, other than JUnit Test cases, 
[IBM has a recommendation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/#N10255) for comparing two floats, using division rather than subtraction - this makes it easier to select an epsilon that works for all ranges of input.

```
if (abs(a/b - 1) < epsilon)
```

As for the value of epsilon, I would use `5.96e-08` as given in [this Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Values_for_standard_hardware_floating_point_arithmetics), or perhaps 2x that value.

(see [comparing float/double values using == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837007/comparing-float-double-values-using-operator))

Comment: Your added reasoning from IBM is helpful.