# Java doubles not comparing correctly in conditional

Tags: java

Trying to use conditionals instead of if statements for double comparison. Debugged step by step several times and can not figure out on what planet java thinks -9==0. When you highlight it, it says false but increases the "zero" double anyways.. The other ones seem to come come across just fine.

My input is:

```
6
-4 3 -9 0 4 1
```

The code:

```
public class HRWPlusMinus {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
    String[] input = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        solveWOF(length, input);
    }

    //solve with for loop
    public static void solve(int length, String[] input) {
        double pos = 0;
        double neg = 0;
        double zero = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            int test = Integer.valueOf(input[i]);
            if (test > 0) {pos++;}
            else if (test < 0) {neg++;}
            else {zero++;}
        }
        System.out.printf("%.6f \n%.6f \n%.6f", (pos/length), (neg/length), (zero/length));
    }

    //solve with conditionals
    public static void solveWOF(Integer length, String[] input) {
        double pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            Double test = Double.valueOf(input[i]);
            zero = (test == 0)? zero++:
            test > 0 ? pos++: neg++;
        }
        System.out.printf("%.6f \n%.6f \n%.6f", (pos/length), (neg/length), (zero/length));
    }
}
```

Top method works, bottom one is the one I'm having issues with.

Comment: In the `solveWOF` method you're checking if `test==0`, not `test < 0`.  Then you check (not an `else` check, it will always be done) if the `test > 0`.

Comment: Java is not wrong.... Never assume that the JVM cannot compute correctly.

Comment: First conditional checks if it is zero, if false, second checks if it is greater than zero.

Comment: Had it as an int but changed it trying to troubleshoot. Didn't make a difference. Also had pos, neg and zero as ints too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that normally a question should not be answered with another, but what are you trying to do with this

```
zero = (test == 0)? zero++:
        test > 0 ? pos++: neg++;
```

I mean why are you assigning to `zero`?

*Explaining:*

if `test` is zero, this reduces to:

```
zero = zero++;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int tmp = zero;    // internal variable
zero = zero + 1;
zero = tmp;
```

that is nothing changed (as explained by EJoshuaS).

If `test` is positive (or negative) it reduces to:

```
zero = pos++;  // or neg++ if test is < 0
```

that is, `zero` will be set to the number of positives (or negatives) so far! That is not wanted, the assignment is wrong in all cases!

Use an `if` as in the other method `solve()`.

Be aware that comparison with doubles can be tricky, see:

1. [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088216/85421)
2. [comparing float/double values using == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6837007/85421)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `zero++` doesn't behave how you think it does. It retrieves the value and then increments it, so you're always assigning the value to itself. You can verify that the following prints zero:

```
int zero = 0;
zero = zero++;
System.out.println(zero);
```

Thus, this line won't work:

```
zero = (test == 0)? zero++:
        test > 0 ? pos++: neg++;
```

Some of the other problems have already been discussed in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I'm counting how many zeros, positives and negative numbers are in my string array.

Comment: @ArcSoftware Inspect your code - you have several lines that aren't doing what you think they're doing. For example, several of your assignments won't do anything - e.g. `zero = zero++` will literally do absolutely nothing. You can verify that fact by running the code I supplied in my answer.

Comment: Have also tried 

    zero += test == 0 ? 1: test > 0 ? pos++: neg++;

Comment: @ArcSoftware Why would you want to add `pos` to `zero`? Also, this has a similar issue to what I describe above - you're incrementing *after* you do the assignment, not beforehand. Again, this isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @ArcSoftware The value of `someInt++` is just `someInt` - that is, the _value_ of `something++` as an expression is unchanged. @EJoshuaS has pointed out multiple times that `something = something++` does _absolutely nothing_.

Answer (score 0):

```
double pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            Double test = Double.valueOf(input[i]);
            pos += (test > 0) ? 1:0;
            neg += (test < 0) ? 1:0;
            zero += (test == 0) ? 1:0;
        }
```

Fixed it, thank you. As suggested I realized that I assigning something that wasn't an assignment.